# R package with both fortran and c++ (Rcpp) code

Tags: r, makefile, fortran, fortran90, rcpp

I am packing a bunch of my functions into an R package. My problem is that I have both .f90 code and c++ (through Rcpp) which I want to be compiled separately in two different shared libraries, also because they need different includes/link options.

I found only the package "grDevices" which has 2 shared libraries, and there the problem is solved using subdirectories with adapted Makefiles, whose syntax is however voodoo for me. Are there other examples out there?

Can I achieve what I want without expliciting everything in a Makefile, for example using just the Makevars file? Any hint appreciated.
Cheers,
domanov

Answer (score 3):

I would start with a `src/Makevars` setting the respective variables for Fortran and C++:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS
PKG_FLAGS
PKG_FCFLAGS
```

as well as

```
FLIBS
FCLIBS
```

See [Section 1.2.1 "Using 'Makevars'" in Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) for more.

Comment: If this is helpful, please consider "accepting" (click on the tickmark only you as question-owner see) and/or "upvoting" (click on up-triangle) as that is how StackOverflow rolls.